# substring search like with scop be able to find scopes

Tags: solr, sunspot-rails

I have schema like this:

```
<fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" omitNorms="false">
  <analyzer type ="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StandardFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="1" maxGramSize="15" side="front"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StandardFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

In my model I have following :

```
searchable do   
    text :content
    text :title
    time :created_at
  end
```

Now what I am trying to search word which can be substring in the records.
If I put scop in search field I am able to find scopes.